# Extract matching words from files

Tags: java, string, search

I have several text files and a data set of several words. I have to match for every text file what are the words that are matching. How can it be achieved?

I initially started with tokenizing each of my text files and then look for each word in the HashMap( of my data set). But this seems to be a very tedious task. I want something that gives me results in seconds.

Comment: how do you read your file?  scanner?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want it to happen pretty fast. Try [elastic search percolator](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-percolate.html). It exactly fits your requirement.

For java api check this [link](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/percolate.html) out.

Comment: I think it should do it. I will give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

did you want the full code or just the concept

I would say create a

//string is the Key and object is the object you want to map to like a count or something
//you can also use generics if using java

HashMap hashMap = new HashMap();

where all they keys are the set of words

then for every word in these files just do

hashMap.get("thewordyouneedtolookup");